# Google Cloud Application and Google database on separate servers

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup my node js project on google cloud and found out I have to do this with a database that is not on the same server. I read in another response that I may need to whitelist the ip that is used for the google cloud node js application, but I read that the ip is not static for google cloud projects. Would anyone be able to point me to a document that could help do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found document that helped me answer this question
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql-postgres